# Are AKKA actors a good solution for optimizing my setup?

Tags: database, concurrency, akka, scalability, actor

I work on a project, where much of concurrent reading and writing to the DB is bringing performance down. Imagine that I need to sort of reindex the entire DB from time to time, so, the simplest way possible is to set a "dirty" flag to true, and let multiple machines grab at the "dirty" items, do some processing,  and then set their state to "clean" again. As you can imagine, this is a paradise for deadlocks.

I want to optimize this, and leave the DB IO operations to one coordinating machine,  and the rest of the possible concurrent computing to other machines. I thought that Akka, with its distributed actor model can be an ideal for for this. My idea is to have the coordinating actor read batches of "dirty" items from the DB, fire off numerous processing actors, passing an item to each one. The idea is that the processing actors will reside on different machines,  but neither the coordinator, nor the processors should be aware of this. This seems to be made possible by, and of the big advantages of using Akka. I want to make this a deployment configuration issue,  to make scaling at will possible.

After the processing actors finish the processing, they can send the result as a message to the coordinating actor,  which will use the same connection to save its state.

Am I going I'm the right direction with this setup?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cluster Singleton](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/cluster-singleton.html) as coordinator. Note that coordination actor will take all requests sequentially, so it should be pretty lightweight. At least you may want to separate bulk reading and writing back. And maybe (if you don't have triggers) also read dirty blocks with pagination to not block actor for a long time. I used iterator defined over a ResultSet (Oracle JDBC drivers automatically do pagination) - and smthng like `case ScheduledBulk if previousBulkFinished => future {getIterator(...).foreach(coordinator ! _)}}`.

If you want fast writes to DB - you may use [Fixed Size Router](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html) to distribute writes between many actors (count < size of your connection pool to DB)